# Polymer and firebase get data with parameter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer

I'm new to polymer and firebase, and I never used json based database. I want to create a chat feature on my web between user and group. I want to display only the messages between the two person that hav conversation. But I don't know how to take some data based on the parameter (in this case the sender and receiver id). It's similar to "select * from table where.." in sql database. I've been trying to look for it for some days, but I can't seem to find the right way to do it. Is it possible?

my data structure should be like :

```
{
"chats":{
   "1":{
      "sender" : "user_id_1"
      "receiver" : "user_id_2"
      "message" : "hello!!"
      "created_at" : "11/08/2017 18:20:07"
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for helping :)

Comment: This video series will probably help you :)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WTQZV5-roY&index=3&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s

Comment: Yes!! It's totally helping me. I don't know why I can't find this before, I just never think that such tutorial exist. Thank you very much for showing me this :)

Comment: Maybe you can accept my answer if it helped you to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

**Firebase Database video series:**
[**The Firebase Database For SQL Developers**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WTQZV5-roY&index=3&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)
1. SQL Database & The Firebase Database
2. Converting SQL structures to Firebase structures
3. Firebase Database Querying 101
4. Common SQL Queries converted for the Firebase Database
5. Joins in the Firebase Database
6. Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database
7. Data consistency with Multi-path updates
8. Securing your data structure with Security Rules